# How Do I Open Up A Javascript Pop-Up in a c# webbrowser?

Tags: javascript, popup

I need to open up a javascript popup in a c# webbrowser.
It keeps escaping and opening up in my default browser.

If someone could help me, that would be amazing
Thanks
John

Comment: What's a c# web browser?

Comment: As in the default web browser that comes with visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use IDocHostShowUI::ShowMessage to catch the popup. This would intercept the "alert" messages, if this is what you are looking for, there is some example code at:

http://www.faisoncomputing.com/samples/programming_samples.htm

The 2nd Example shows how to implement it.

Comment: Hey there, thanks a lot for answering, the URL of the javascript link is going to be constantly changing, and I tested out all of the samples you showed me, and it still popped out.